# Listening event outside MainPage class calling method multiple times on button click event (repetetively)

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, android-activity, silverlight-5.0

I have a situation where I have to manage the button click event outside `MainPage` class (suppose in Class `B`).  Here is the code that I'm using:

```
 namespace TEST
 {
     public partial class MainPage: UserControl 
     {
         public event Action simpleEvent;
         public MainPage() 
         {     
         }

         private void comboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
         {
             switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem as string) 
             {
             case "UInt8":
                 B obj4 = new B(this, fileContent, "UInt8");
                 break;
             case "UInt16":
                 B obj1 = new B(this, fileContent, "UInt16");
                 break;
             case "UInt32":
                 B obj2 = new B(this, fileContent, "UInt32");
                 break;
             case "UInt64":
                 B obj3 = new B(this, fileContent, "UInt64");
                 goto
             default;
             default:
                 MessageBox.Show("check");
                 break;
             }
         }
         private void ButtonClick_EVENT(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
         {
             // I try to listen outside the class this way.
             if (simpleEvent != null)
                 simpleEvent();
         }
     }

     Class B 
     {
         public B(MainPage Obj, byte[] fileContent, string type)
         {
             switch (type = Obj.comboBox1.SelectedItem as string)
             {
             case "UInt8":
                 {
                     //do something 
                     break;
                 }
             case "UInt16":
                 {
                     //do something
                     break;
                 }
             case "UInt32":
                 {
                     //do something 
                     break;
                 }

             case "UInt64":
                 {
                     //do something 
                     goto
                     default;
                 }
             default:
                 {
                     break;
                 }


             }
             Obj.simpleEvent += () = > MyMethod(Obj);
         }

         public void MyMethod(MainPage Obj) 
         {
             // This MessageBox repeats 2 times on second time button click
             // and 3 times on 3rd button click .
             // It should be called once even on second/third/fourth etc. button clicks.
             MessageBox.Show("Repetition check");
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem is my method is called repetitively.  For example, when I click the button the first time it will be called only once (which is good). and if I click the button again the message box pop-up comes up 2 times and again pop-ups 3 times on 3rd attempt.

What I want is to pop-up this message box only once on the click (even if I keep on clicking on the button one after the other click).

EDIT: The new updated code is the actual situation i was trying to make it short so last time i didn't include to much code (because i was not suspecting that part).

What i am trying to do is :
I have to select 1 data type among 4 given data type at run time (uint64/32/16/8)(which will be data type for reading a file ("fileContent" in constructor call), but it's not related to question i asked, so leaving too much discussion on it).After selecting that data type i click the `button` to display something. (so each time i first i select "data type" from `combo box` and then i press `button` to display some data corresponding to that data type then i again select another data type from combo box and then again i press "button" but this time it pop-ups message 2 times, and when i repeat the same 3rd time it pop-ups messagebox 3times).

Suppose first i selected "`uint64`" in combo box at run time (in the first attempt) and then i click button to display messagebox it will pop-up the message box once.Now without closing the application my second selection to combo box is on `uint32` (On second attempt) and again i click to "button" this time this message box is popped 2 times. I don't know why? and on third attempt it pop-ups 3 times.

(1) Why message box repeats ?
Thanks for the help in advance, I really wanna know the reason for it, not able to understand yet.

Comment: This seems like its a multicast delegate problem, you must be adding 'MyMethod()' multiple times into your simpleEvent.Why don't you check if simpleEvenyt is null before adding it in your B class constructor?

Comment: The code you've shown won't replicate this problem.  You're adding the handler to each event exactly once.  It would seem that your actual code is slightly different than the code you've posted here.

Comment: @GrantWinney so you mean according to the code i have written it will becalled only once ?There is some other problem ?

Comment: @Servy so you mean according to the code i have written it will becalled only once ?There is some other problem ?

Comment: @user234839 Yes, the problem you describe will not happen with this code.  Your actual code must be different in some way.

Comment: @Servy i have edited the code to explain well. Could you please see it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `B` object every time your combobox is changed.  That adds a new handler every single time, without ever removing the previous handlers.  You need to either unsubscribe the old handler when you go to add a new one, or only ever add one handler and simply modify the data that it relies on so that that handler acts appropriately when it fires.

Comment: How to unsubscribe the the old handler ?

Comment: @user234839 `something.SomeEvent -= handlerToRemove;`

Comment: thanks a lot How to unsubscribe the the old handler ? specially in this situation of code

Comment: @user234839 I just showed you how to unsubscribe a handler.  You use the `-=` operator.

Comment: Yes i had understood that but th eproblem would be where to apply this operator "-=" in current code scenario?

Comment: @user234839 `MyMethod2(Obj)` is not a delegate, you need to provide the delegate that was used to subscribe to the method to unsubscribe it.

Comment: yes i deleted that question, I just got that. But where to apply "Obj.simpleEvent -= () => MyMethod(Obj);" in my code acording to scenario is big problem because i have to first select data type from combo then click button and then again select data type from combo and then again button.

Comment: @user234839 That's not the same handler that you attached; that's trying to remove an entirely different handler that simply has an equivalent implementation.  You'd need to "remember" the first handler that you attached, and then remove it whenever a new handler is added.  While this is possible, in the end you're simply doing way, way more work than you should be.  The solution here is to avoid attaching multiple handlers in the first place, not to be removing them after the fact.  I don't even see the need for any event to begin with here.

Comment: sorry ? You mean this is not a good place to put "Obj.simpleEvent -= () => MyMethod(Obj);" ? I couldn't understand which place in my code have you specified to put this line  ?

Comment: @user234839 I see no reason for `B` to even *know* about `MainPage`, to have a reference to it, or to be subscribing to any of its events.  Non-UI components shouldn't have knowledge of UI layers using them.  Create a `B` object when the combobox is change, remember it as an instance field, and invoke it's method when the button is clicked.  Done.  Far, far simpler.

Comment: @"Create a B object when the combobox is change" : Combo box is not changed it's still the same only i select the different data type from the same combo box and then press button which contains the "simpleEvent" to display some data related to that data type selected from combo box and then again change the data type from same combo box.

Comment: @user234839 Yes, create a new `B` object when the selection is changed, that's what I meant.  For that matter, there's no real need for a `B` object, it doesn't hold onto any meaningful data; just print out the combo boxes current selection on button click.  You don't even need a second class for that, or if you do, you don't need and event handler on the combo box or a stored reference to the class to do that.

Comment: Thanks but it's bit confusing to me , I have already created different object for each "Class B" constructor call, see "B obj1 = new B(..)" and "B obj2 = new B(..)", there are different objects (obj1,obj2,obj3 etc.) . I am not able to understand yet. Could you please give me a piece of code explaining in bit more detail ? Thanks would be a big help.

Comment: i need tthe second class.I do some manipulation on "fileContents" in B class.

Comment: @user234839 Then just create an instance of the class right in the button click handler.  Within that handler you can have `new B(fileContent, comboBox.SelectedItem).MyMethod();`.  Done.  Then remove all of the stuff in which the `B` object subscribes to a handler from your control.